# Is it possible to install VMWare Server on Amazon's EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, virtualization, vmware, kvm

We are looking to move all of our systems to a virtualized env.

We will be going with EC2 and it appears that if we can install something like vmware or KVM on EC2 then create VMs as needed it would be the most cost effective solution for us.

Is this possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

EC2 is already a virtualized environment; it uses the Xen virtualization manager, which is an open source equivalent to VMWare server.  You can create VMs with EC2, customize them and save them as Amazon Machine Images (AMIs).

See the [Amazon documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/GettingStartedGuide/) for a more comprehensive introduction.